# Plotting term frequency over time: Twitter API, JSONL file, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, text-mining

I have a code with to analyse a JSONL (lines) file containing a Twitter user's timeline (last 3200 tweets). The code should plot the frequency of a specific term over time using pandas and Vincent. But for some reason, every time I run the script for a JSONL file the outputted 'time_chart.json' doesn't contain any values for the term frequencies. Needless to say, the chart produced at my localhost only depicts the axis. Any idea where I got it wrong? Thanks in advance! I'm using Python 3.

```
import vincent
import pandas
import json
import sys
import json

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  fname = sys.argv[1]

  with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    dates_UN = []
    for line in f:
      tweet = json.loads(line)
      terms_hash = [term for term in tweet['text']]
      if 'UN' in terms_hash:
          dates_UN.append(tweet['created_at'])

# a list of "1" to count the terms
ones = [1]*len(dates_UN)
# the index of the series
idx = pandas.DatetimeIndex(dates_UN)
# the actual series (at series of 1s for the moment)
UN = pandas.Series(ones, index=idx)

# Resampling / bucketing
per_day = UN.resample('1D').sum().fillna(0)


time_chart = vincent.Line(per_day)
time_chart.axis_titles(x='Time', y='Freq')
time_chart.to_json('time_chart.json')
```

For your information: the JSONL file consists of information that is structured in the following way:

```
{  
   "created_at":"",
   "id":,
   "id_str":"",
   "text":"",
   "truncated":,
   "entities":{  
      "hashtags":[],
      "symbols":[],
      "user_mentions":[],
      "urls":[]
   },
   "source":""   rel=\"",
   "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
   "user": ........ etc.
}
```